# Branch.io present navigation controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, branch.io

im using branch.io SDK in my apps. My Apps is using UITabBarController. I can manage to open the link to my select view but its view as modal, and when i close it it shown my initial screen while i already bypass the screen when user login.
How i can manage to present it not as modal and close to some view except the main view? this is how i setup the branch in my appdelegate.m

```
Branch *branch = [Branch getInstance];
[branch initSessionWithLaunchOptions:launchOptions andRegisterDeepLinkHandler:^(NSDictionary *params, NSError *error) {
DetailController *controller = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailView"];
[branch registerDeepLinkController:controller forKey:@"userid"];
[branch initSessionWithLaunchOptions:launchOptions automaticallyDisplayDeepLinkController:YES];
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

Alex from Branch.io here: you're using our basic, default deep link routing method. This simply takes the link data and invokes the specified view controller as a modal on top of whatever else your app usually does when opening up (as you are seeing).

This is often sufficient for a basic deep link implementation, but it sounds like you'd be better off building something custom. The good news is Branch makes this very easy, because once we have returned your link data to you, you can use that data for *anything you like.* You can find some documentation about getting started with this [here](https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/deep-link-routing/advanced/ios/#building-a-custom-deep-link-routing-method).